# 1 out of 100 fetch requests fail and causes an error. How to continue with the program?

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch

I am making 100 fetch requests to an api and something is wrong with nr 35 (it wont return a json file). The problem is I get this error and my program crashes. How can I catch this error, put it to the side and continue with the rest of the program?

```
const pokeapiPromise = [];
for (let i = 600; i <= 700; i++) {
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
  pokeapiPromise.push(fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()));
}

Promise.all(pokeapiPromise).then((result) => {
  const pokemon = result.map((data) => ({
    name: data.name,
  }));
});
```

Since the problem is that a json-file is not returned, I tried this:

```
pokeapiPromise.push(
  fetch(url).then((res) => {
    if (res.status == 200) {
      res.json();
    }
    else{
      console.log("nope")
    }
  })
);
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the response to request 35?

Comment: Have you tried to just to attach catch?

Comment: The endpoint at https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/608 returns nothing.

Comment: First I get this: GET https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/635 404

Comment: Then i get this: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

Comment: I tried to attach a catch but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You have no error handling, so of course things go south if there's an error.  You need proper error handling so you can absorb the error and continue on.  If your `.catch()` isn't working, then it's apparently because you aren't doing it correct and the only way someone can help you is if you show the code for what you tried and explain exactly what happened with that code (including precise error messages).

Comment: That’s fair. I now realise I didn’t provide the right info and should have included my code with the catch example I tried.

Comment: Also you are hammering the API. Please add a setTimeout in the .done to call the next one in a respectful manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the URL returns an HTTP 404 error for 609 (at least for me):

https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/609

...and it returns "Not Found" as body, which obviously does not represent valid JSON.

So you could check the `ok` property of the response object. Here is a demo limited to just 3 of those URLs (608-610):

```js
const pokeapiPromise = [];
for (let i = 608; i <= 610; i++) {
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
  pokeapiPromise.push(
    fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.ok ? res.json() : { httpStatus: res.status }) // this 609 case
        .catch(err => ({ error: err.message }))); // other errors
}

Promise.all(pokeapiPromise).then((result) => {
    console.log(result.map(data => data.name || data));
});
```

Comment: "*which obviously does not yield valid JSON.*" - no, that's not obvious. There is no reason why a HTTP 404 response shouldn't contain a JSON error document.

Comment: Btw, I'm not getting an error on that page, your demo snippet prints `[
  "lampent",
  "chandelure",
  "axew"
]` for me.

Comment: Oh, strange, it still produces a 404 for me, just on that middle one. I updated the text for both comments.